# Splitting Deck in-half error? Really easy, but I messed up

Tags: java

I am trying to split a deck of cards into two arrays (one for the user, one for the computer)

```
static String [] deck = [52 cards here]
             static String [] userDeck = new String [26];
             static String [] computerDeck = new String [26];

         public static void deckSplit ()
             {
              for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
              userDeck[i] = deck[2 * i];
              computerDeck[i] = deck[(2 * i) + 1];
              }
            }
```

but i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at war.Deck.deckSplit(Deck.java:47) [the part about the computerDeck]
    at war.War.main(War.java:28) [where i called the decksplit method]
```

EDIT:

```
 static String [] deck = {"2 of Diamonds" + "\n2 of Hearts"+"\n2 of Clubs"+ "\n2 of Spades"+ 
                    "\n3 of Diamonds"+ "\n3 of Hearts"+ "\n3 of Clubs"+ "\n3 of Spades"+ 
                   "\n4 of Diamonds"+ "\n4 of Hearts"+ "\n4 of Clubs"+ 
                   "\n4 of Spades"+ "\n5 of Diamonds"+ "\n5 of Hearts"+
                   "\n5 of Clubs"+ "\n5 of Spades"+ "\n6 of Diamonds"+ 
                   "\n6 of Hearts"+ "\n6 of Clubs"+ "\n6 of Spades"+
                   "\n7 of Diamonds"+ "\n7 of Hearts"+ "\n7 of Clubs"+  
                   "\n7 of Spades"+ "\n8 of Diamonds"+ "\n8 of Hearts"+  
                   "\n8 of Clubs" +"\n8 of Spades"+ "\n9 of Diamonds"+ "\n9 of Hearts"+ 
                   "\n9 of Clubs"+ "\n9 of Spades"+  "\n10 of Diamonds"+  
                   "\n10 of Hearts"+ "\n10 of Clubs" + "\n10 of Spades"+   
                   "\nJack of Diamonds"+ "\nJack of Hearts"+ "\nJack of Clubs"+ 
                   "\nJack of Spades"+ "\nQueen of Diamonds"+ "\nQueen of Hearts"+  
                   "\nQueen of Clubs"+ "\nQueen of Spades"+ "\nKing of Diamonds" +   
                    "\nKing of Hearts" + "\nKing of Clubs" + "\nKing of Spades"+   
                   "\nAce of Diamonds"+ "\nAce of Hearts"+  "\nAce of Clubs" 
                    + "\nAce of Spades"};//52

 static String [] userDeck = new String [27];
 static String [] computerDeck = new String [27];
```

That's 52 cards. I am not sure how to get it to split tho :/

Comment: What value of `i` does it throw the Exception for?  Are you *sure* that you have allocated 52 cards in your deck?

Comment: static String [] userDeck = new String [27];
     static String [] computerDeck = new String [27];

Comment: My arrays look okay for the user and computer deck. it throws the exception for 1. i counted 52 cards in my array, but it throws the exception.

Comment: The missing code (the initialization of `deck`) may be where the problem lies.

Comment: `deck` does not contain 52 elements, only one. You're *concatenating* strings.

Comment: Yeah, print out the length of `deck` and you will find it only has one element.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to have the "\n" characters in your array elements either.  If you need that, add it when you print the value.

Comment: thank you so much all of you. i have a lot to learn and this is a site which I promise to contribute in the future to. you guys are the best. pcnThird just saved my life

Comment: Don't deface your question.  It belongs to the community now.  If you don't want your code to appear publicly on the internet, then don't post it in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating one big string:

```
static String [] deck = {"2 of Diamonds" + "\n2 of Hearts"+"\n2 of Clubs"+ ...
```

will add all your strings together

change the `+` to `,`

```
static String [] deck = {"2 of Diamonds" , "\n2 of Hearts"+"\n2 of Clubs" , "\n2 of
```

If you print `deck[0]` you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
static String [] deck = {"2 of Diamonds" + "\n2 of Hearts"+"\n2 of Clubs"+ "\n2 of Spades"+ 
                    "\n3 of Diamonds"+ "\n3 of Hearts"+ "\n3 of Clubs"+ "\n3 of Spades"+ 
                   "\n4 of Diamonds"+ "\n4 of Hearts"+ "\n4 of Clubs"+ 
                   "\n4 of Spades"+ "\n5 of Diamonds"+ "\n5 of Hearts"+
                   "\n5 of Clubs"+ "\n5 of Spades"+ "\n6 of Diamonds"+ 
                   "\n6 of Hearts"+ "\n6 of Clubs"+ "\n6 of Spades"+
                   "\n7 of Diamonds"+ "\n7 of Hearts"+ "\n7 of Clubs"+  
                   "\n7 of Spades"+ "\n8 of Diamonds"+ "\n8 of Hearts"+  
                   "\n8 of Clubs" +"\n8 of Spades"+ "\n9 of Diamonds"+ "\n9 of Hearts"+ 
                   "\n9 of Clubs"+ "\n9 of Spades"+  "\n10 of Diamonds"+  
                   "\n10 of Hearts"+ "\n10 of Clubs" + "\n10 of Spades"+   
                   "\nJack of Diamonds"+ "\nJack of Hearts"+ "\nJack of Clubs"+ 
                   "\nJack of Spades"+ "\nQueen of Diamonds"+ "\nQueen of Hearts"+  
                   "\nQueen of Clubs"+ "\nQueen of Spades"+ "\nKing of Diamonds" +   
                    "\nKing of Hearts" + "\nKing of Clubs" + "\nKing of Spades"+   
                   "\nAce of Diamonds"+ "\nAce of Hearts"+  "\nAce of Clubs" 
                    + "\nAce of Spades"};//52
```

The code above contains one element consisting of concatenated strings. This is why you get an exception when you try to access the non-existent second element. See this to see how this array should be created: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Quick example:

```
static String [] deck = {"2 of Diamonds", "2 of Diamonds", /* etc */};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the code for how you are populating the deck?  I would check it's length and make sure it's 52, I duplicated what you are trying to do here to the best that I could without seeing the rest of your code and this seems to work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Cards {
    static String[] deck = new String[52];
    static String[] userDeck = new String[26];
    static String[] computerDeck = new String[26];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0;i<52;i++) {
            Cards.deck[i] = "Card " + i;
        }
        Cards.deckSplit();
    }
    public static void deckSplit ()
    {
        System.out.println(Cards.deck.length);
         for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
             Cards.userDeck[i] = Cards.deck[2 * i];
             Cards.computerDeck[i] = Cards.deck[(2 * i) + 1];
         }
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Cards.userDeck));
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Cards.computerDeck));
         System.out.println("userDeck:" + Cards.userDeck.length);
         System.out.println("computerDeck:" + Cards.computerDeck.length);
   }

}
```

And it outputs this:

```
52
[Card 0, Card 2, Card 4, Card 6, Card 8, Card 10, Card 12, Card 14, Card 16, Card 18, Card 20, Card 22, Card 24, Card 26, Card 28, Card 30, Card 32, Card 34, Card 36, Card 38, Card 40, Card 42, Card 44, Card 46, Card 48, Card 50]
[Card 1, Card 3, Card 5, Card 7, Card 9, Card 11, Card 13, Card 15, Card 17, Card 19, Card 21, Card 23, Card 25, Card 27, Card 29, Card 31, Card 33, Card 35, Card 37, Card 39, Card 41, Card 43, Card 45, Card 47, Card 49, Card 51]
userDeck:26
computerDeck:26
```